# get notification before connectivity changes

Tags: android

I am working over a project. In this, I am running a background service, in this their is connection between device and server. I want when device is connected to internet the service gets started and connection gets builtup between server and device and when internet disconnected the connection between server and device also gets disconnected
For this I have to send request to disconnect the connection, but that also requires internet connection that is currently not available.

So I want to disconnect the connection between server and device before internet gets disconnected. For this I need the stage i.e prior to internet disconnected that may be like *Going to disconnect internet*.

The code I tried is not sufficient for this work

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        try{
        if(netInfo.isConnected() && netInfo != null){
            System.out.println("Connected to internet");
            context.startService(new Intent(context,MessageService.class));
        }


        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("Not Connected to internet");
            context.stopService(new Intent(context,MessageService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell any soln for this?

Comment: `and when internet disconnected the connection between server and device also gets disconnected`. Don't worry, it will. ;-).

Comment: its not disconnecting, we have to disconnect to let openfire xmpp server know that connection is disconnected

Comment: If there is no internet there is also no connection between server and client.  What i mean is that further data cannot be exchanged. What you mean is that the server is unaware of the invalid connection. Indeed that is problematic. Please rephrase your problem.